# Azure Web App not updating after mvn azure-webapp:deploy

Tags: java, azure, maven, vaadin

I'm using Azure to host my Java Spring Boot application. I have created a trial to test this solution and I managed to deploy my application following this tutorial [Deploy with Azure](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/cloud-deployment/azure) which is using the `azure-webapp-maven-plugin` and the command `mvn azure-webapp:deploy`.

My problem is that when I'm making changes inside my application and I want to apply them in my Azure Web App but nothing actually update when I reach the page, here is the message after using the deploy command :

```
[INFO] Updating target Web App...
[INFO] Successfully updated Web App.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource to PATH\custom-dashboard\target\azure-webapp\custom-dashboard-98d69249-24aa-4729-8b7d-b7ff4b419823
[INFO] Trying to deploy artifact to custom-dashboard...
[INFO] Deploying the war file custom-dashboard.war...
[INFO] Successfully deployed the artifact to URL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  39.637 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-04T13:15:59+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But as a proof of the success inside Azure, I can indeed find inside the Deployment Center the deployment log with the `(Active)` tag. [image]

So I have searched for an option on Azure where we could choose the latest running version but I didn't find anything so far.

Here is also my `pom.xml` configuration if you need it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom-dashboard</artifactId>
    <name>Project base for Spring Boot and Vaadin Flow</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.5.3</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Excluding so that webjars are not included. -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
            <artifactId>a-vaadin-helper</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Include JUnit 4 support for TestBench and others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-log4j1_2</artifactId>
            <version>[2.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.4</version>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                             the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
                <configuration>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--
                      Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                      package.json and main.js files.
                      It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
                  -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaVersion>V2</schemaVersion>
                    <resourceGroup>DefaultResourceGroup-NEU</resourceGroup>
                    <appName>custom-dashboard</appName>
                    <pricingTier>F1</pricingTier>
                    <region>northeurope</region>
                    <runtime>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <javaVersion>jre8</javaVersion>
                        <webContainer>jre8</webContainer>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>JAVA_OPTS</name>
                            <value>-Dserver.port=80</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                    <deployment>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.war</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </deployment>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Thank you for any help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you only running `mvn azure-webapp:deploy`?

Make sure you run `mvn package` first, or `mvn package azure-webapp:deploy`. Otherwise it will just re-deploy the same WAR file. Include the `-Pproduction` flag if you want to run it in production mode.

Edit:

I set up a project myself and could reproduce your issue. After running `mvn azure-webapp:config` again twice and updating both `Application` and `Runtime`, it seems to work.

This did two changes to the `pom.xml`, try these out:

1. Add `<deploymentType>war</deploymentType>` under `<configuration>` in the `azure-webapp-maven-plugin`.
2. Change `<webContainer>jre8</webContainer>` to `<webContainer>TOMCAT 9.0</webContainer>`.

Comment: Hi, yes I am running `mvn clean package -Pproduction` then `mvn azure-webapp:deploy`. I checked with a Tomcat on a server to host the generated WAR to see if it's the right one generated and it is. That's why it's weird

Comment: @Erick Lumme any idea ?

Comment: Sorry @JérémiePoisson, nothing else comes to mind right now.

Comment: @JérémiePoisson spent an hour or two setting this up myself and I could reproduce your issue, I've updated my answer.

Comment: oh I didn't do the config part for `Runtime` i think that's what I was missing. I also manually add the `deploymentType` tag and it seems to update now ! Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind marking the answer as accepted?